# Erro ao gravar registro de log do banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, log, trigger

Eu tenho um banco de dados com MySQL. Estou fazendo os *log* desse banco. A maioria está funcionando, mas não tô conseguindo pegar o id do registro que foi modificado.

**Exemplo**: ao mudar algum dado, ele deveria ficar salvo nos *log* o id do registro que foi alterado, mas apenas aparece `NULL`. Estou fazendo eles usando  *triggers*, e uma delas é:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `empresa_AFTER_INS` AFTER INSERT ON `tabela` FOR EACH ROW
insert into `log`.`log_tabela`(campos_do_banco,data_hora,acao,usuario)
values (NEW.campos_do_banco,NOW(),'insert',@usuario);
```

Como que eu faço para que o `id` do dado fique salvo nos registro de *log*?

Comment: Não seria isto que quer? `values (OLD.Id, NOW(), 'insert', @usuario);`?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que apenas o preenchimento está errado, seria algo assim (depende do que quer gravar e como vai organizar o *log*):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `empresa_AFTER_INS` AFTER INSERT ON `tabela` FOR EACH ROW
    insert into `log`.`log_tabela`(campos_do_banco, data_hora, acao, usuario)
        values (NEW.Id, NOW(), 'insert', @usuario);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/TriggerLog.sql).

Comment: eu vi mais tarde que eu tinha esquecido de mandar o id ;) Obrigada